# using google fonts in nextjs with sass, css and semantic ui react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I have a next.config.js file that has the following configuration:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withSass(withCss({
  webpack (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          publicPath: './',
          outputPath: 'static/',
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    })

    return config
  }
}));
```

This is great because it runs my semantic ui css files.

Now I have a problem. I can't seem to successfully import any google font url. I tried downloading the ttf file into my file path and tried to reference it with the @import scss function. However I get a GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/Cabin/Cabin-Regular.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) error

Here is what I'm trying to do with google font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  src: url('/fonts/Cabin/Cabin-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
}

$font-size: 100px;
.example {
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}
```

I have also downloaded the relevant npm dependencies:

```
"@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
"@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^2.0.0",
"next": "^7.0.2",
"node-sass": "^4.9.4",
"react": "^16.6.0",
"react-dom": "^16.6.0",
"semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
"semantic-ui-react": "^0.83.0",
"url-loader": "^1.1.2"
```

Answer (score 11):

I know in **Next.js 9.3**, you can copy the **@import** statement from Google Fonts:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&display=swap');
```

and place this in some css file, lets say `styles/fonts.css` like so:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&display=swap');

.jost {
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}
```

Then import that inside of your global `_app.js` file like so:

```
import `../styles/fonts.css`
```

Now you have global access to that class containing the Google Font in every next.js page

Comment: I would consider this as the best practice.

Answer (score 8):

I think the other solution is to use fonts directly from Google. Just customize [`_app.js` file](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-app) and add a `<link rel="stylesheet" />` in the `<Head />`

**Example _app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin"
            rel="stylesheet"
            key="google-font-cabin"
          />
        </Head>

        <Component {...pageProps} />

        <style global jsx>{`
          body {
            font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
          }
        `}</style>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what would you consider as best practice? housing the font in local folders or what you just suggested?

Comment: I would go with the approach when I use fonts from Google [via API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) instead of downloading them locally. Some benefits I see: 1. If I need to add more fonts from google I dont need to download anything just add a font name to the URL and that's it 2. No need to tweak next.js webpack config to load fonts

Comment: That works great. I would put it to _document.js though.

Comment: I would consider a local copy best practice - along with the css font display setting you can avoid an unecessary network request

Answer (score 2):

```
 class NextApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component } = this.props
    return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Component {...pageProps} />

            <style jsx="true" global>{`

              @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

              body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
              }

            `}</style>

          </React.Fragment>
        </Provider>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Including the font url from Google Fonts in styled-jsx worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support) you can now add global css by updating the `_app.js` file and importing your css style. Follow the steps below

1. Create custom `_app.js` file in the pages directory by following the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).
2. Add your `styles.css` file to the pages directory.
3. Include the styles as below

```js
// _app.js

// Import styles
import './styles.css'

// Function to create custom app
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

// Export app
export default MyApp
```

and done. These styles `styles.css` will apply to all pages and components in your application. Due to the global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, you may only import them inside `_app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the files into the static folder for it to work, must've been a specific setup for rendering images and fonts in nextjs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a functional custom app, then you can add google fonts or any cdn linked fonts to the head of the whole app as follows:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

// Custom app as a functional component
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  let pageProps = {};
  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
  }

  return { pageProps };
};

// Export app
export default MyApp
```

now you can use css to apply the font family to the body element to get the font applied throughout the webiste, as shown below.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hhis is now how I am currently loading external fonts nonblocking. In _document.js head:

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '</script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" media="print" onload="this.media=\'all\'" /><script>' }} />
```

- dangerouslySetInnerHTML and some script hacking to work around `onload` otherwise being removed from _document.js [until this is resolved](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014)

[source](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/)